# Way to set <Box /> type with styled in MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

`@material-ui/styles` support next way to redefine default styles:

```
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const StyledBox = styled(Box)({
  color: 'red'
});
```

By default `Box` is like `<div />` and I can change it by passing `component` props:

```
// somewhere in code
<StyledBox 
  component="span" 
>
  Some text
</StyledBox>
```

And this example doesn't work:

```
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const StyledBox = styled(<Box component="span" />)({
  color: 'red'
});
```

Is there a way to make a component definition for Box at the styling stage using `styled`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example showing how to do this. You can't pass `<Box component="span" />` (an element) to `styled` because it is expecting a component type not an element (i.e. an instance of a component). Instead you need to create a new component type (`SpanBox` in the example below) that wraps `Box` and passes through any props or ref while specifying the props you want to control (e.g. `component="span"`).

```
import React from "react";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const StyledBox = styled(Box)({
  color: "red"
});

const SpanBox = React.forwardRef(function SpanBox(props, ref) {
  return <Box ref={ref} component="span" {...props} />;
});
const StyledSpanBox = styled(SpanBox)({
  color: "purple"
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledBox>red div 1</StyledBox>
      <StyledBox>red div 2</StyledBox>
      <StyledSpanBox>purple span 1</StyledSpanBox>
      <StyledSpanBox pl={3} border={1}>
        purple span 2
      </StyledSpanBox>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit styled Box with props]

Comment: How can I send props to the styled box such as: src, alt, etc.?